JPA: How to join OR get fields from custom function in JPQL
So, i have some configuration
public class MyPostgreSQL9Dialect extends PostgreSQL94Dialect {
    public MyPostgreSQL9Dialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("cust_func", new StandardSQLFunction("cust_func", StandardBasicTypes.CLASS));
    }
}

cust_func return three fields (id, name , date) and with one arg (bigint)
I try this as JPQL:
   select pt from Info pt
   inner join 
   function('cust_func', pt.id /* as example */ ) pt2 on pt2.id = pt.id; 

OR i need to get fields
select t.id , t.name, t.date from function('cust_func', pt.id /* as example */ ) t

whats wrong ?
